# Use unary plus operator in a type of TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I know that putting "+" infront of variable will make it output a number and I'm trying to make a type in TypeScript and it is of type boolean but I want to make it such that when user access this type it will convert boolean into 1 or 0. Here is my code:

```
type State = { showRightSidebar?: boolean, +value?: boolean }
```

The editor is screaming at me for putting the + infront of value. Am I doing it wrong? What is the correct way of doing this

What I want to achieve I dont know if it possible or not but here it goes:
So I want the user to be able to assign True or False but when access State.value it will return 0 or 1.

Comment: Do you want the type to be a boolean? Or do you want it to be 0 or 1? It can't be both. It's possible to take a value that's a boolean, and then write some code to create a number from that boolean (one way being the `+` operator that you mentioned), but that's going to be done with javascript code, not typescript type definitions.

Comment: +value will convert string to number

Comment: @NicholasTower I was thinking by putting +value that means user can assign true/false but when access the object[value] it will return 0 or 1

Comment: @MightAsWell Ignoring the typescript part for the moment, how do you intend for the javascript code to have that behavior? getters/setters? proxies? Remember that typescript is all at compile time. It doesn't change what the language is capable of doing, it just tries to describe it.

Comment: @NicholasTower right so what I'm trying to do is not possible then. alright thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I would put this as a comment but my rep isn't high enough.

What you are doing is creating a type alias called State that is an alias for an object with a certain shape. In your case, that shape has two optional properties of 'showRightSidebar' and 'value'. Are you expecting 'value' to be the value of show right side bar? It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Regardless, you can't have a property name with a '+' in it. You also cannot specify a conversion operator as part of a type alias declaration. 
If you wanted 'value' to be a zero or 1 you could do this.

```
type State = { showRightSidebar?: boolean, value: 0 | 1 }
```

That will declare 'value' as a number where the only valid values are 0 and 1.
If you want to declare this as a boolean then you will need to convert to 0 or 1 when you access the 'value' property.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but that is not what I wanted. Let me update my post so it is clearer

Answer (score 0):

I want to closed this question because clearly what I'm trying to do is impossible. For those of you who need to use this. you can 1st declare the type of boolean and then when you call the variable just add + infront it shall gives you 0 for false and 1 for true.